# Customize UITableView section border color for each section

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am using a UITableView with grouping.  My first group I have built a custom cell with no background color, and I would also like to remove the border around the cell.  How can I do this just for one section?

For my first cell, I would like to set the border/seperator style to [UIColor clearColor].

[image]

**EDIT:** Apple does this in their contacts app, and I wanted to design something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what Apple uses for its contact heading is `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` for section `0`, instead of a cell in the first section. You can still specify a transparent background and the pinstripe will show behind it. The border will not be there as grouped table view section headers do not have borders.

Whether you built your custom cell in Interface Builder or using code, it should be a fairly trivial task to migrate those views from a `UITableViewCell` to a `UIView` for use with `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`.

I don't know if you'll be able to keep the **Details** title for, say, section `1`, unless you make a label containing that word and add it to the section `0` header view manually.

Comment: If you change it to be a section header then it wont scroll as it previously did. i.e. it will stick at the top of the screen whilst the section scrolls under it which is probably what you didn't want.

Answer (score 4):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if(indexPath.section == 0){

cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I also got this to work directly inside of the cellForRowAtIndexPath!

Answer (score 3):

If i understood your question, in the cellForRawIndexPath you should add-

```
if(indexPath.section==0){

//set the style you wish to add only to the first section

}
```

good luck

**EDIT**

I use this function for that -

```
+(void)setTransparentBgToCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell{
        UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 44.0f)];
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
        [backgroundView release];
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

shani

Comment: Yeah, but all I can find is to set it for the whole tableView: tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

Comment: You are right. i have added a function i used in one of my apps, try that.shani